# Select all _id from mongodb collection with c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have large document collection in mongodb and want to get only _id list. Mongodb query is `db.getCollection('Documents').find({},{_id : 0, _id: 1})`. But in C# query

```
IMongoCollection<T> Collection { get; set; }

...

List<BsonDocument> mongoResult = this.Collection.FindAsync(FilterDefinition<T>.Empty, new FindOptions<T, BsonDocument>() { Projection = "{ _id: 0, _id: 1 }" }).Result.ToList();
```

throw exeption `InvalidOperationException: Duplicate element name '_id'.`
I want to get ***only*** _id list, other fileds not needed. Documents may have different structures and exclude all other fileds manualy difficult.

What C# query corresponds to the specified mongodb query `db.getCollection('Documents').find({},{_id : 0, _id: 1}`?

UPDATE: Do not offer solutions related query large amounts of data from the server, for example like

```
this.Collection.Find(d => true).Project(d => d.Id).ToListAsync().Result;
```

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55417118/1257607) may help as well

Answer (score 5):

Since your using C# driver I would recommend to use the `AsQueryable` and then use linq instead.

In my opinion it is better since you wouldn't need the magic strings and you would benefit from your linq knowledge. Then it would look something like this

```
database.GetCollection<T>("collectionname").AsQueryable().Select(x => x.Id);
```

Comment: Documents include many data. If using plain select on quearyable collection, driver **load all data for all document**. Large number of large documents is huge load on the server, i **need only _id list**.

Comment: I would be surprised if the driver would implemented that way, also it is an index so it would probably fetch it from the index not the collection itself. Have you bench-marked the performance?

Comment: My benchmark is excecution query time and the shortest time query for me is `db.getCollection('Documents').find({},{_id : 0, _id: 1}`. Your query in result is (in bson) `{ "aggregate" : "Documents", "pipeline" : [{ "$project" : { "_id" : "$_id" } }], "cursor" : { } }`

Comment: Alexey, maybe you are right. But your comparison is incorrect. You need to compare query plans. I assume that query plans are the same.

Comment: @rnofenko, i understand, that both queries return same result, but i want get specific query with specific driver. I am wrong with driver - they not load all data, but query plans not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Alexey is correct, solutions such as these

```
var result = (await this.Collection<Foos>
                       .Find(_ => true)
                       .ToListAsync())
             .Select(foo => foo.Id);
```

Will pull the entire document collection over the wire, deserialize, and then map the `Id` out in Linq To Objects, which will be extremely inefficient.

The trick is to use `.Project` to return just the `_id` keys, before the query is executed with `.ToListAsync()`.

You can specify the type as a raw `BsonDocument` if you don't want to use a strongly typed DTO to deserialize into.

```
var client = new MongoClient(new MongoUrl(connstring));
var database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
var allIds = (await collection
        .Find(new BsonDocument()) // OR (x => true)
        .Project(new BsonDocument { { "_id", 1 } })
        .ToListAsync())
    .Select(x => x[0].AsString);
```

Which executes a query similar to:

```
db.getCollection("SomeCollection").find({},{_id: 1})
```