# MongoDb use filter to match a list

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, intersection

I have a list of `BsonDocument`:

```
   var list = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName); 
   var myIds = list.Find(_ => true)
    .Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("_id"))
    .ToList();
```

that contains:

> ```
> myIds = "{ 
> { "_id" : "cc9d9282-c9d2-4cba-a776-ffddsds274d5" },  
> { "_id" : "2c1ddd82-c9d2-4dda-afr6-d79ff1274d56" },  
> { "_id" : "ss969281-c9d2-4cba-a776-d79ffds274d5" }  
> }"
> ```

And want to query like this:

```
var deleted =list.DeleteMany(Builders<MessageExchange>.Filter.In("_id", myIds));
```

I also have tried the following:

```
var filter = new BsonDocument("_id", new BsonDocument("$in", new BsonArray(myIds)));
var deleted = list.DeleteMany(filter);
```

Returns the attribute `DeletedCount = 0` 
Could somebody point what seems to be wrong about the filter?

Comment: Contains what exactly? A list of `BsonDocument`? or something parsed from JSON input into something else? Something like `.In("_id", myIds.Select( e => e._id))`  would be the general approach, but it all depends what type of object the things in the list actually are.

Comment: maybe first convert that list from `JSON` string to `List<string>` and then try filtering

Comment: is there any error message? because I suppose `In` translates to `$in`, it should work

Comment: have you tried executing it for `find`?, it returns `DeleteResult` object, have you explored that?

Comment: the filter seems fine, have you tried filtering records in `MessageExchange` collection from MongoDB's terminal to verify that records do exist against these Ids and problem is with this filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to extract the *_id* from the BsonDocument like this:

```
var extractedIds = myIds.Select(x => x["_id"].ToString()).ToList();
```

After which you can use it in the filter.

```
list.DeleteMany(Builders<MessageExchange>.Filter.In("_id", extractedIds));
```

Make sure that the *_id* part of the filter matches that of the MessageExchange class

Another way to do so is by making it strong typed:

```
list.DeleteMany(Builders<MessageExchange>.Filter.In(x => x.Id, extractedIds));
```

Comment: Could you point out which is the approach for the not string typed option (MessageExchange class)?

Comment: @DanielV, that depends on your MessageExchange class, if you could add that to the question, I can give it a go.

Comment: I just answered based on yours

Answer (score 0):

This works as well (based on Skami's answer):

```
var filter = new BsonDocument("_id", new BsonDocument("$in", new BsonArray(extractedIds)));
list.DeleteMany(filter);
```

therefore is not tied to the `MessageExchange` class.