# Delete multiple documents using MongoDB driver doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to delete multiple documents in MongoDB using `MongoDB.Driver` with `vb.net`. However, it doesn't work and gives the error:

```
'Unable to cast object of type 
'MongoDB.Driver.SimpleFilterDefinition`2[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument,System.String]' 
to type 'MongoDB.Driver.IClientSessionHandle'.'
```

The code is as follows:

```
Public Function DeleteAllContent(item As Content) As String
   Dim db As IMongoDatabase = DatabaseService.GetDBcontext()
   Dim filterId = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq(Of String)(("id"), item.ID)
   Dim filterResourceId = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq(Of String)(("resourceId"), item.ID)

   db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("Contents").DeleteMany(filterId, filterResourceId) <<exception here

   Return String.Empty
End Function
```

**Tried the followings but didn't work**

1.

```
 Dim db As IMongoDatabase = DatabaseService.GetDBcontext()
 Dim filterResourceId = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq(Of String)(("resourceId"), item.ID)

 db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("Contents").DeleteMany(filterResourceId)
```

2. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55452045/1108500)

   ```
       Dim db As IMongoDatabase = DatabaseService.GetDBcontext()
       Dim filterResourceId = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq(Of String)(("resourceId"), item.ID)
       Dim result = db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("Cards").Find(filterResourceId).ToList
       Dim extractedIds = result.Select(Of BsonDocument)(Function(x) x("id").ToString()).ToList()
       Dim deleteList = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.In(Of String)("id", extractedIds)

       db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("Cards").DeleteMany(deleteList)
   ```

**Solution:** `DeleteMany` doesn't take multiple filters. So that needs to be combined. The following code worked.

```
 Dim filterResourceId = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq(Of String)(("resourceId"), item.ID)

 db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("Contents").DeleteMany(filterResourceId)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no overload for DeleteMany that takes two filters as parameters, so since the best-matched overload is `(IClientSessionHandle session, FilterDefinition<TDocument> filter..) (c#)`, the error says that the provided filter (`filterId`) cannot be converted to IClientSessionHandle). So you just use it in the wrong way, you should create a single filter that will include any conditions you need

Comment: I did, still didn't work.             
`Dim filterResourceId = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq(Of String)(("resourceId"), item.ID)
db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("Cards").DeleteMany(filterResourceId)`. It just doesn't delete anything.

Comment: if it doesn't delete anything (which I assume also means that the previous error was gone), then you use a wrong filter. Pay attention that in the document a `id` field is called `_id`

Comment: `_id` filed is not the issue. `'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]'.'` is the issue. From the 2nd option that I tried.

Comment: you should better explain what and where do happen, the current exception is clear: you use the wrong type, the expected one collection of `string`s, but you provide a collection of `BsonDocument`s, Is it compile-time error or runtime?

Comment: idk vb, but I assume `extractedIds` is a collection of `BsonDocument`s, but `Filter.In` requires a collection of `string`s.

Comment: `Dim db As IMongoDatabase = DatabaseService.GetDBcontext()
 Dim filterResourceId = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq(Of String)(("resourceId"), item.ID)

 db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("Contents").DeleteMany(filterResourceId)`
This has worked. You were correct in saying the DeleteMany doesn't take multiple filter.